# Display parameter estimates in table format

Tags: sas

I'm using SAS for the first time and am unable to find out how to display parameter estimates for a regression analysis in table format.  Currently it just spits out fixed-width text in the output window.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of ways to do this.  The easiest is to use HTML as your output destination.  The results will then be displayed in an HTML table.

```
ods html; *Turns on the HTML output.  Look at SAS doc on how to set styles, locations, etc;

<your code here>

ods html close; *Turns off the HTML output;
```